# Remove duplicates in tuple without using set()

Tags: python, set, duplicates, tuples

```
x = (1,1,-13,8,5,0,4,-1,-4)

a = filter(lambda i,j: i == j, x)

print(tuple(a))
```

I am getting an error instead of the correct answer `(1,-13,8,5,0,4,-1,-4)`.
What is my error?

Comment: A `filter` callable is only ever passed *one* argument; what makes you think it would be passed two?

Comment: And why the arbitrary restriction that a set cannot be used? What is your actual goal here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Yeah, feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me...

Comment: Without any further feedback as to what you actually need, I'm going to assume you wanted to remove duplicates whilst preserving order.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you remove duplicates from a list in Python whilst preserving order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x = (1,1,-13,8,5,0,4,-1,-4)
seen = []
answer = []
for elem in x:
    if elem not in seen:
        seen.append(elem)
        answer.append(elem)
print(tuple(answer))
```

Ouput:

```
(1, -13, 8, 5, 0, 4, -1, -4)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = (1, 1, -13, 8, 5, 0, 4, -1, -4)

print(tuple([item for index, item in enumerate(x) if item not in x[:index]]))
```

Output:

```
(1, -13, 8, 5, 0, 4, -1, -4)
```

Answer (score 1):

`filter` will iterate through `x` and pass each and every element to the lamdba function. But, it will be passing only one element at a time. So, the lambda function cannot accept two elements (unless the last one has a default value).

Apart from that, there are so many solutions without using `set`. For example, you can use `collections.OrderedDict`, like this

```
x = (1, 1, -13, 8, 5, 0, 4, -1, -4)
from collections import OrderedDict
print tuple(OrderedDict.fromkeys(x))
# (1, -13, 8, 5, 0, 4, -1, -4)
```

if the order of elements doesn't matter, you can use a normal dictionary itself, like this

```
print tuple({}.fromkeys(x))
# (0, 1, 4, 5, 8, -13, -4, -1)
```

Or you can use a temporary `seen` list, like this

```
x = (1, 1, -13, 8, 5, 0, 4, -1, -4)
seen, result = [], tuple()
for item in x:
    if item not in seen:
        seen.append(item)
        result += (item, )
print result
# (1, -13, 8, 5, 0, 4, -1, -4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you may have duplicates anywhere in the list and not only consecutive repetitions, filter won't help you much.

You can use `reduce` with a custom function:

```
reduce(lambda acc, e: acc if e in acc else acc + (e, ), x, ())
```

Also if you wanted to remove successive repetitions only, it's pretty easy too:

```
reduce(lambda acc, e: acc if e in acc[-1:] else acc + (e, ), x, ())
```

Or hand-crafted code

```
rv = []
for i in x:
    if i not in rv:  # any repetition
    if i not in rv[-1:]  # only successive repetitions
        rv.append(i)
result = tuple(rv)
```

Just for the kicks, here's are a couple of answers that use `filter`:

```
map(lambda i: x[i], filter(lambda i: x[i] not in x[:i], range(len(x)))

[sub[0] for sub in filter(lambda sub: sub[0] != sub[1], [x[i:i+2] for i in range(len(x)-1)])]
```